# How to read large sas file with pandas and export to parquet using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, large-files

i'm trying to make a scrip that read a sasb7dat file and export to parquet using pandas, but i'm struggling to increase my performance with large files (>1Gb and more de 1 million rows). Doing some research, i found that using multiprocessing could help me, but i can't make it work. The code runs with no errors, but no parquet files are created.

Here is what i got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

arq = path_to_my_file

def sas_mult_process(data):
    for i, df in enumerate(data):
        df.to_parquet(f"{'hist_dif_base_pt'+str(i)}.parquet")
        
file_reader = pd.read_sas(arq, chunksize=100000,encoding='ISO-8859-1',format='sas7bdat')
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    executor.map(sas_mult_process, file_reader)
```

Can anyone see where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You use the term `multiprocessing` all over the place yet your code is not using multiprocessing but rather multithreading. It appears that you are trying to break up the input file into `dataframe` chunks and have each chunk become a separate output file. If that is so, you would want to pass each chunk to you worker `sas_mult_process`, which would then process that *single* chunk. I am assuming that converting the input to parquet involves more than just I/O but rather entails some CPU processing. Therefore, multiprocessing would be a better choice.

```py
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

arq = path_to_my_file

def sas_mult_process(tpl):
    """
    This worker function is passed an index and single chunk
    as a tuple.
    """

    i, df = tpl # Unpack
    
    # The following f-string can be simplified:
    df.to_parquet(f"hist_dif_base_pt{i}.parquet")

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    file_reader = pd.read_sas(arq, chunksize=100000,encoding='ISO-8859-1',format='sas7bdat')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(sas_mult_process, enumerate(file_reader))
```